# Glide Layout Null Kotlin "must not be null"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I'm trying to show image as full screen on seperate layout with activity when onclick to image With Glide. Same Glide code works for showing in product details activity but not for fullscreen activity. Keeping the value on constant and passing, checked by printing, it gets the image url from firebase like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/Product_Image1625509993393.png?alt=media&token=xxx something is wrong with xml layout that Glide cant shown.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: **showfullimage** **must not be null**
at com.shop.ui.activities.ShowFullImageActivity.loadimg(ShowFullImageActivity.kt:36)
at com.shop.ui.activities.ShowFullImageActivity.onCreate(ShowFullImageActivity.kt:29)

**onclick intent on productdetails activity:**

```
iv_product_detail_image.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this@ProductDetailsActivity, ShowFullImageActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE, product.image)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**ShowFullImageActivity.kt**

```
class ShowFullImageActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var mProductImage: String = ""


    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (intent.hasExtra(Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE)) {
            mProductImage =
                intent.getStringExtra(Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE)!!
        }
        println(mProductImage)

        //full screen load

        loadimg()

    }
    private fun loadimg() {

        Glide
            .with(this@ShowFullImageActivity)
        .load(mProductImage) // Uri or URL of the image
        .centerCrop() // Scale type of the image.
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_placeholder) // A default place holder if image is failed to load.
        .into(showfullimage)
    }
}
```

**show_full_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.ShowFullImageActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/showfullimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/product_detail_image_height"
        android:background="@color/colorImageViewBackground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing this

```
setContentView(R.layout.show_full_image)
```

Without this all controls are null.

Answer (score 0):

1)setContentView is needed before load View

2)showfullimage need to be init before using it

So you may try to add some code in ShowFullImageActivity.kt:

```
override fun initData() {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.show_full_image)
        showfullimage = findViewById(R.id.showfullimage)
        ...
    
}
```